# Variable within XPath Expression

Tags: javascript, variables, xpath

I am having difficulties placing a variable within my XPath expression.

I want to make a search term that I can modify from an input, and use it in the XPath expression, but the second example below is failing.

**1. This works**

```js
var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate("//option[text()[not(contains(., 'test'))]]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for (var i = 0; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++) {
  console.log(nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i));
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>cat</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>dog</option>
</select>
```

**2. This fails**

```js
var searchTerm = 'test';
var xPath = '"' + "//option[text()[not(contains(.,'" + searchTerm + "'))]]" + '"';
console.log(xPath);

var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for (var i = 0; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++) {
  console.log(nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i));
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>cat</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>dog</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Try to print `xPath`, you'll notice that it contains too many quotes.

Comment: Thanks Caramiriel, I thought that the beginning and ending quotes were needed, but it seems that's what messed it up for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to keep track of opening and closing quotes. Instead, you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```js
var searchTerm = 'test';
var xPath = `//option[text()[not(contains(., '${searchTerm}'))]]`;
console.log(xPath);

var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate(xPath, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for (var i = 0; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++) {
  console.log(nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i));
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>cat</option>
  <option>test</option>
  <option>dog</option>
</select>
```

This is ES2015+ syntax. If you want ES5 solution, use:

```
var xPath = "//option[text()[not(contains(., '" + searchTerm + "'))]]"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems that I just needed to remove the beginning and ending quotes. And thanks for recommending the template literals, that's something I'm going to use going forward! :)